# Maven and Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2

I use Flex Builder to generate data binding for my Flex app with Blaze DS. When I compile my pp from Flex Builder everything works just fine. But when I try to compile it with Maven I has a problem with missing libraries.

I discovered that maven miss the following libs:

- fds.swc, fds_rb.swc
- fiber.swc, fiber_rb.swd
- serializers.swc, serializers_rd.swc

As a temporal solution I added this libs to my maven repository and everything seems to work fine, but I would like to know names of the proper libs to add to my pom.xml

Comment: From where did you got your libraries you added to the maven repos ?

Comment: I took them from my Flex Builder installation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you really using "Flex Builder" (e.g. v3) or are you using "Flash Builder" (v4)?

Also, are you using Flexmojos to compile the Flex project in Maven?

Regardless, you can/should just use the Adobe Flex Maven repository set up by Sonatype/Flexmojos.  It is located here:

https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/

I use Nexus to proxy this repository for me, but you could just add it to your pom.xml file(s).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the SWC's you mentioned aren't open-source by adobe and not included in the sdk, we found manually uploading them to our repo was the only way to overcome the broken build.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can find that swc in this repository now

```
<repository>
    <id>sinusgear</id>
    <name>SinusGear repo</name>
    <url>http://maven.sinusgear.com/maven_repo/</url>
</repository>
```